# `gcloud compute copy-files`: network error when copying files

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

When I am trying to copy a file from my Windows local to google compute engine (`Rhel 6`), using `gcloud` command I am getting network error as given below:

```
Fatal: Network error: Connection timed out
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.copy-files) [C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-clo
ud-sdk\bin\sdk\scp.EXE] exited with return code [1].
```

Here is the command I used -

```
C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\java>gcloud compute copy-files --plain test.txt  [userid@DEST_instance:~/directory_name] --zone us-central1-f
```

Could anyone point out what is causing this error?